# Bind event to right-click

Tags: event-handling, highcharts, right-click

How do I bind to or recognize a right-click event?

I have a scatter plot where left-click adds a point at the clicked location; I would like right-click to remove the point (if present).

This is my current code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
   chart: {
       renderTo: 'container',
       events: {
           click: function(event) {
               var cs = [Math.floor(event.xAxis[0].value),
                         Math.floor(event.yAxis[0].value)];
               this.series[0].addPoint(cs);
           }
       },
        type: 'scatter',

   },
   ... etc. ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:[Making Highcharts support right click context menu](http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/making-highcharts-support-right-click-context-menu/)

Comment: I appreciate the LMGTFY attempt, but this isn't really helpful -- 1) I don't want to patch HighCharts as I want to be able to use future releases and 2) I don't want a context menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full solution:  I did not figure out how to capture right-click events.

**But here's a workaround for clicking on the chart background:**

- have the user do a shift-click
- supply a callback as before
- in the callback, inspect the event.  If shift was pressed, do something different

Here's what the callback might look like:

```
function clickChart(event) {
    var isShiftPressed = event.shiftKey;
    if(isShiftPressed) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something different
}
```

The event object has boolean attributes `shiftKey` (and `altKey`).

**Here's a workaround for removing points:** (actually, it's not a workaround -- I just didn't realize there was an easier way!)

- points have their own events
- just set up a callback that removes points when they're clicked

Example:

```
function clickPoint(event) {
    this.remove();
}

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        renderTo: 'chart',
    },
    series: [{
         point: {
             events: {
                 click: clickPoint
             }
         }
    }]
});
```

Note: the documentation is misleading, at the least, but the jsfiddle examples seem to be correct.  It seems to show that the `point` options are *not* in `series`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are only a few events supported by Highcharts.
for ref : https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/introduction-to-highcharts-events/

To add custom events, such as

- double click (including mobile devices)
- right click (context menu)
- mouse over
- mouse out
- mouse down
- mouse move

we can add a plugin

> highcharts-custom-events

https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-custom-events

hope you find this helpful and solves your problem.